# Django ORM Query to get number of currently subbed user

Tags: python, django, sqlite, orm, django-orm

I use an Event log that tracks subscriptions and unsubscriptions to given mailing lists.

My objective is to hit the database one time (sqlite) to get the number of subscribed users, I don't need the objects, just a number.

models.py

```py
class MailingListEvent(models.Model):
    """Events on mailing lists.

    This represents subscribes, unsubscribes, and bounces.  We'd like
    to understand what happens and when, not just the current state of
    the system.

    """
    class EventType(models.TextChoices):
        SUBSCRIBE = 'sub', 'inscription'
        UNSUBSCRIBE = 'unsub', 'désinscription'
        BOUNCE = 'bounce', 'bounce'

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mailing_list = models.ForeignKey(MailingList,
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
    event_type = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=EventType.choices)
```

So far I found only this solution to work with :

```py
def user_subscribe_count(mailing_list):
    """Return the number of users currently subscribed to the mailing list.

    We want to know how many users are currently subscribed.  Note
    that individual users might subscribe and unsubscribe multiple
    times.  Other (future) events could happen as well.
    """
    user_list = MailingListEvent.objects.filter(mailing_list=mailing_list).values_list('user',flat=True).distinct()
    users_subscribed = list()
    for user in user_list:
        user_state = user_current_state(User.objects.get(pk=user),mailing_list)
        if user_state.event_type == MailingListEvent.EventType.SUBSCRIBE:
           users_subscribed.append(user_state)
    return len(users_subscribed)

def user_current_state(user, mailing_list):
    """Return user's most current state on the provided mailing list

    Return the most recent event associated with this user in this
    mailing list.

    """
    try:
        the_user = MailingListEvent.objects.filter(
            Q(event_type=MailingListEvent.EventType.SUBSCRIBE) |
            Q(event_type=MailingListEvent.EventType.UNSUBSCRIBE),
            user=user, mailing_list=mailing_list).latest(
                'event_timestamp')
        return the_user
    except MailingListEvent.DoesNotExist:
        return MailingListEvent(
            user=user, mailing_list=mailing_list,
            event_type=MailingListEvent.EventType.UNSUBSCRIBE)
```

I know there is a .count() method on Django, but converting to list already hits the database anyway.

Can someone suggest a query that would return the number of users currently subscribed given this model please ?

Comment: So this is counting the number of subscribe events minus the number of unsubscribe events?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Not exactly, a single user could theoratically make multiple unsub events through the unsubscription link we provide. I guess we could limit that behaviour and then do SUB - UNSUB to get the correct number.

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `user_current_state`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Added the implementation to the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate the `User`s with the latest `MailingListEvent` for that `MailingList` by using a [**`Subquery`** expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

User.objects.alias(
    latest_action=Subquery(
        MailingListEvent.objects.filter(
            mailing_list=mailing_list,
            user=OuterRef('pk')
        ).order_by('-event_timestamp').values('event_type')[:1]
    )
).filter(latest_action='sub').count()
```

If the latest action was `BOUNCE`, then this will *not* be counted as a subscribed user.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: Django's [**`DateTimeField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField)
> has a [**`auto_now_add=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField.auto_now_add)
> to work with timestamps. This will automatically assign the current datetime
> when creating the object, and mark it as non-editable (`editable=False`), such
> that it does not appear in `ModelForm`s by default.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ! I implemented this and tested the solution in a case where the output should have been 2 (One user simply subscribed, the other did sub-unsub-sub-unsub-sub), sadly it returned 0.

Comment: @Benjamin_Mourgues: what do you get when you use `.values('latest_action')` instead of `.filter(latest_action='sub').count()`, this should normally list the latest action per `User`.

Comment: I get `FieldError: Cannot select the 'latest_action' alias. Use annotate() to promote it.`

Comment: @Benjamin_Mourgues: and use `.annotate(..)` instead of `.alias(..)` in that case.

Comment: So I edited your suggested function with `annotate` instead of `alias`, it still returns 0. However did apply `.values('latest_action')` to see what outputs it produces, and it's a long query set full of {'latest_action': None}. Thanks for the help by the way, I appreciate.

Comment: @Benjamin_Mourgues: are you sure you use the right `mailing_list`? It looks that maybe for another mailing list the users are subscribed/unsubscribed?